# Why throws for IOException in method signature is needed for only specific cases?

Tags: java, throws

```
public static String doSomething()  {
    String name = "ABC";
    try {
        throw new IOException();
    } finally {
       return name;
    }
}
```

O/p:ABC

However below code needs throws in the method signature. Is it because return statement is missing or any other reason?

```
 public static String doSomething() throws IOException {
    String name = "ABC";
    try {
        throw new IOException();
    } finally {
       System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first method *can't* throw an `IOException`. The `return` statement in the `finally` block effectively swallows any exception that *would* have been thrown (i.e. the `IOException` that you explicitly throw in the `try` block).

Your second method absolutely *will* throw an `IOException`, and because that's a checked exception, you need a `throws` clause to tell the caller that.